# asp.net mvc... something equivalent of wordpress theme?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

You know how it takes a couple of clicks to install wordpress themes. Is there a way to accomplish this with ASP.NET MVC website?

Also, what would be the most efficient way for a programmer to apply/implement web-designer's design to the ASP.NET MVC website?

I guess both of my questions are heading in the same direction, but they are slightly different from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theme support in in native MVC is virtually non-existent.

However MVC's low level HTML generation makes it quite easy to incorporate any pure HTML/CSS theme you desire.

Look on Google for "free CSS themes" etc.

WordPress themes can be different! Often they can rely upon scripting and also use dependencies deeper into the "core" of WP itself and as such become unusable with MVC.

For MVC, I suggest a little knowledge of HTML/CSS will take you a long way - you will get the results you desire and in a much "cleaner" format.